# Is there a way to make custom keyboard shortcuts take precedence over app shortcuts in MacOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, macos-mojave

I have been attempting to create a keyboard shortcut for opening a new terminal window, but the problem I keep running into is that different apps utilize shortcuts that will conflict with my custom ones, and these take precedence over my shortcuts while the app is in focus (or even just open in ToDoist's case).

I've added my shortcut by making an automator service that opens a terminal window and assigning it a "service" shortcut in the appropriate system preferences menu (Keyboard->Shortcuts->Services).

Is there a way to change it so my global shortcuts will be executed instead of the app's shortcuts?

Comment: If your shortcut conflict exists as an actual menu item, yes. If it's truly a Mac global, no. Could you add specifics to your question?

Comment: Sure I just added how I added the shortcut. When you say the "conflict" exists as a menu item, are you referring to the conflicting shortcut or mine?

One conflict was with todoist, which had a preference that I could disable the shortcut. Another conflict is when terminal is open, it has a shortcut that conflicts that I cannot disable. I'm fine with conflicts with Apple programs because I can just avoid them, but I more am concerned with not having to disable shortcuts for new apps every time I download new software

Comment: My current combo is control+command+T, but that's not my question or problem. I don't really care WHAT combo I use, what I care about is the fact that todoist (or any application) when in focus takes precedence over my shortcut. I am perfectly willing to change keyboard shortcuts, what I don't want to do is have to worry that my shortcut will be broken depending on what application happens to be open at the time.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not being clear enough, so I apologize. Let me try and explain myself more clearly. 
I'm asking a generalized question because the specific combo is not what is bothering me. I have noticed from this experience (along with trying several different shortcuts and noting the exact same behavior) that my shortcuts are preempted by shortcuts for applications that are in focus. I want to know if this behavior can be mitigated or if application shortcuts are ALWAYS higher priority than shortcuts set for services in the shortcuts menu.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. As a follow up, is there another way to set shortcuts other than in the keyboard shortcuts menu that WOULDN'T have this limitation?

Comment: Had you just answered my first question an hour ago, we wouldn't have needed all this back & forth. I'm done. This is not a helpline. You have to ask the question you need the answer to & add relevant detail if requested to clarify.